# How to backup the data which can't be accessible?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, backup

My Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop doesn't boot, so I am trying to get my data from the old Ubuntu using Live USB(**RUNNING UBUNTU FROM THE USB WITHOUT INSTALLING**). But when I try to copy some files I get error as " You have no permission to access this". So what is the way that I have to handle to backup my data.

Comment: What don't you have access to? The original system or wherever you're trying to copy the files to?

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have permission to read the old data or permission (or the correct mount options) to write to wherever you're trying to rescue this data to.

The simplest method here would be to just <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and run `pkexec nautilus`. That should give you root access to everything and then you can sort the permissions out when you've restored that data somewhere.

If you just can't write to the place you're trying to backup, open a terminal and run `mount` to see how it's mounted. If it's got `ro` instead of `rw` in its mount options, there's the problem. I don't know the specifics but you'll need to run something like:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1
```

Obviously, you'll need to change that to the applicable device (based on the output of `mount`).

Comment: I would actually do: sudo mount -o remount,rw,users /dev/sdb1
To make sure that ordinary users can access the mounted filesystem

Comment: Hello Sir I have taken the screen shot and I have uploaded it, can you please see me the link and tell me what to do to take the data. [IMG]http://i41.tinypic.com/sbk6ef.png[/IMG] - @oli